# Arabic translation for iPhone

Tags: iphone, localization, arabic

What localization prefix do I use for an Arabic translation of the text for an iPhone application?  For example for a French translation I use the prefix "fr" which creates a directory "fr.lproj".  In actuality the lproj prefixes are the two letter country codes for the country.  But there isn't a country for Arabic.  So what localization prefix do I use for an Arabic translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the iPhone specifically, but for Arabic it is typical to use "ar" as the prefix. If there are specific subsets, it has the form of "ar-XXX" but  don't know what the possible XXXs are.

Generally, it is good to follow one of the ISO standards, I am guessing that if you use fr then you need ISO 639-1 and not 639-2. [See this link.](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

Answer (score 1):

BCP 47 definition for Arabic:

Type: language
Subtag: ar
Description: Arabic
Added: 2005-10-16
Suppress-Script: Arab
Scope: macrolanguage

Also here's a list of the Languages abbreviations in ISO 639-2 format:
[ISO 639-2 language codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

I hope it helps.